# Position child elements in Container

Tags: css, html, positioning

I am trying this:
there is a picture element Which is wrapped inside a container div

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">
        <img src="b.jpg" alt="b" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to place the child elements such a way that the top and left of the picture is always 25% of the height & width of the container div. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If that is the only requirement, you can just do it by adding a padding on the inner div.

According to W3C, it those percentages should refer to the dimensions of the outer div.

> Like margin properties, percentage values for padding properties refer
>   to the width of the generated box's containing block

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

For the height, it will only work if your inner div is the only element inside your outer div (because the inner div will determine the height of the other).  So for you example, it'll work.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but I don't think that's true. The inner div can't calculate padding as a percentage of the parent div's width/height.

Comment: @JezenThomas I added a W3C quote to convince you :)

Comment: Ah, so it is! Very interesting; [tested here](http://jsfiddle.net/pcW9C/). However, technically it doesn't fit the original requirements, since padding only takes into account the parent element's width, not both height and width. You get +1 because I learned stuff.

Comment: Hmm; indeed you're right.  However, in this case it will work, because the inner div is the only child of the outer div.  So their heights will be the same, meaning the percentage will work for the height as well (because it will be relative to its own content).  You can see this effect in your fiddle as well.  If you specify no height on the outer div, the height percentage seems to work.

Comment: @JezenThomas one last note though: I do believe this solution would make most sense, because it sounds like the poster is really just looking for a way to add a wide empty margin between the picture and its container.  In that case, I would prefer using margin/padding to using positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
#container {position: relative;}
#container #a {position: absolute; left: 25%; top: 25%;}
```

Here's a working fiddle: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xzw7C/)

Comment: I dont understand why is my question downvoted. Did i ask something that is already asked here? I dont  think so!

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but considering the fact that there are over 3.4 million questions on Stack Overflow, your question has *probably* been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
#container { position:relative; }
#container img { position:absolute; top:25%; left:25%; }
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCpXJ/)**